# Stopping a CancellationTokenSource which times out after a given TimeSpan to keep its state?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a method that accepts a `CancellationToken` which allows a user of the method to cancel what it is doing. Within the method I used this `CancellationToken` along with a `CancellationTokenSource` to created a linked `CancellationTokenSource`.

```
var timeoutTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(msTimeout));
var timeoutAndCancelTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(
        timeoutTokenSource.Token, cancelWaitToken);
```

I then start a `while` loop that continually checks to see if some value has reached a target, otherwise I `await` a `Task.Delay`. The loop has two exit conditions, if the target value is reached or if the `timeoutAndCancelTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested` is true.

When the loop exits I can interrogate `timeoutTokenSource` and `cancelWaitToken` to determine if the loop cancelled as a result of a timeout, it was cancelled, or if the target value was reached.

The issue I see is that when the loop exits, the `timeoutTokenSource` is still counting down. So if there is only a few milliseconds left on the timeout that I could possibly make false assumptions about what happened within the loop.

**Is there a way to stop a `CancellationTokenSource` so that it does not timeout?**

Comment: Other than setting a timeout, is any other method being passed the `CancellationTokenSource` to manually cancel the token?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to stop a CancellationTokenSource so that it does not timeout?

Wrong question. (BTW, it's not possible to stop one).

The correct question would be "How do I determine if the loop cancelled as a result of a timeout, it was cancelled, or if the target value was reached?"

And the answer is to fix this:

> The loop has two exit conditions, if the target value is reached or if the timeoutAndCancelTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested is true.

Your loop should only exit if the target value is reached. It should pass the (linked) `CancellationToken` into `Task.Delay`.

Then, when you `catch` the `OperationCanceledException`, you check your `cancelWaitToken` and `timeoutTokenSource.Token` to see which one is cancelled.

> So if there is only a few milliseconds left on the timeout that I could possibly make false assumptions about what happened within the loop.

Yes. If you change your loop exit condition, you will only know if it has reached its target value or not. It is possible that *both* cancellation tokens may be signalled by the time you check them, but I believe this is a benign race condition. If `cancelWaitToken` is signalled, does it really matter whether it timed out?

Comment: This is basically what I ended up going with in the end. Thanks Stephen!