# ThreadPoolTimer and stop/do work/resume pattern

Tags: c#, timer

If I use `ThreadPoolTimer` the typical syntax is

```
ThreadPoolTimer PeriodicTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer((source) =>
{
    //
    // TODO: Work
    //
}, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

If I use `System.Timer` the typical way is

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000);

static void Main()
{
  timer.Elapsed += async ( sender, e ) => await HandleTimer();
  timer.Start();
}

private static Task HandleTimer()
{
  try
  {
     timer.Stop();
    //
    // TODO: Work
    //
  }
  finally
  {
     timer.Start();
  }
}
```

So I can avoid the flood if my job takes longer than timer's interval to complete.

What shall I do to achieve the same goal by using `ThreadPoolTimer`?

Comment: I assume the best approach is to use `CancalationTokenSource` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046910/stopping-a-cancellationtokensource-which-times-out-after-a-given-timespan-to-kee.